# Numerical approximation to the Wasserstein metric?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, probability-distributions

Are there numerical methods for approximating/calculating the Wasserstein metric in particular cases?

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two density functions with the same support. How can I calculate the Wasserstein metric for these two models?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are. First note that the Wasserstein metric is, after discretization, the solution of a linear program (LP) that can be fed into any LP solver.

Moreover, there are specialized algorithms, try googling for "Earth-Movers-Distance" (mostly Wasserstein-1).

Then is the Benamou-Brennier framework which puts optimal transport for Wasserstein-2 into the framework of fluid-mechanics, see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002110050002).

Also you may want to look at the numerical method [here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140975528?journalCode=sjisbi) for the Wasserstein-1 distance.

In the end, it really depends, what your goals are, and how you discretize your density functions.

Comment: I am also interesting in the numerical method for the distance of Wasserstein type. But this distance is a bit different. For the previous two marginal distribution $f$ and $g$, I would like to know whether it is possible to calculate the following distance: $$\inf_{P: X\stackrel{P}{\sim}f, Y\stackrel{P}{\sim}g, E^{P}[Y|X]=X }E^{P}[c(x,Y)].$$ Of course, the probability distributions $f$ and $g$ satisfy some conditions called increasing in convex order such that the set of such probability $P$ is non empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire emerging field of numerical approximations to Wasserstein metrics.

See the freely available book by Gabriel Peyré and Marco Cuturi for a good starting point:
[Computational Optimal Transport (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00567)